# File.ReadAllText System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException when directory exists and nothing has changed with the app in a year

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

This is a desktop app that runs on a schedule every morning, starting this week it started throwing this error and nothing has changed with this app in a year.  The file location verified still exists, again nothing has been changed.  Infra department claims no changes have been made to the server also.

```
var template = File.ReadAllText("./Templates/franchise.html");
```

I am at a complete loss as to what is happening here.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does File.Exists("./Templates/franchise.html") return in that place?

Comment: And also, what does Path.GetFullPath(".") return?  Is it the desired directory?

Comment: In this case, the only thing I could recommend is wrapping that code in a `try/catch` statement and catch the `DirectoryNotFoundException`, the you can write that exception out to a log or something to give you details.

Comment: Running the app locally everything is fine and it returns the expected path...the folder is located inside the current directory ... example:  <app location>/templates/franchise.html  I can navigate to it on the server and open the file no problem.

I can push code to check but its a long process here w/ compliance and all that so I cant get an answer immediately or even this week for that matter.  I'm going to try the try-catch

Comment: @Trad is it an unmapped drive, if so, this could be the issue then.

Comment: @Codexer does the drive need to be mapped when it just a directory inside it's current directory?  What would change this if it was working fine previously?

Comment: @Trad it may need to be, maybe your policies where you are have that unmapped? A drive getting unmapped could be from many different things, updates, installs, policies etc. and I can't of course tell from just the information given. I've winessed this happen before a few years ago, the company I worked for and when they would do updates to servers, 9/10 times our mapped drives would get unmapped somehow.

Comment: @Codexer Thanks, I will follow up with our infra department to see if this is the case.

Comment: Because that has already been verified or I've been told its all verified, I cant do it myself because compliance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with permissions, if the scheduled app doesn't have the read permission anymore on that folder, this problem could lead to this error. Check if you have permissions, and if still no clues, try to check Event Viewer on Application filter.

Comment: I received the error from Event Viewer, that's how I found out it was having issues with the directory since the app itself is missing a proper try-catch here.  We tried to correct the permissions with the service account with no luck.

Comment: Could the file be marked as "already opened"? If it's this the problem, the error is really messy cos it refers to the folder... but try to find it out